# Paypal v-zero credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I try to integrate a payment method with Paypal Express Checkout and I wanna use the v-zero sdk. To configure my php server I need an accessToken.

On my dashboard from [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) I can see a 'v.zero SDK' section with a 'Generate Credential' button, so I assume I need to generate these credentials to get my accessToken.

But the 'select an account' list under 'Request Credentials' is empty and the button is disabled.

How can I get an account to generate my credentials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown list is a list of Business type sandbox account you created in developer.paypal.com

You will need to first create some Business sandbox accounts [here](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). Account created will then appear in the dropdown list for you to generate credentials.

Comment: I already tried to do this and the listbox was still empty. But today I decided to do it again with the difference that I created an US account instead of French (cause I m French). And it works with US ! Could you confirm that an FR account is available in production ? Thanks

Comment: That's because v.zero is only available for merchants in the United States, Canada, Australia, Europe, Singapore, Hong Kong, Malaysia and New Zealand. In legal terms, you have to be domiciled in a supported country.

Visit here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/bt-vzero-overview/